# Need a pop up message to display for a few seconds after executing selenium code

Tags: java, selenium

I have written a simple code using Java Selenium.
After quitting the firefox i want a pop up message to be displayed in the desktop saying "script executed."
This is my Selenim code-

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");

    driver.quit();
    }
}
```

is there a way to do it??
if so, please guide me.

Comment: We all want a lot of things. What research did you do into this question before asking someone else to do it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to display on the desktop you can look for an IDE with a GUI builder like Eclipse (with plugin), NetBeans or other.
Or if you want to code it take a look at this sample:

```java
private void window()
{
  JFrame jf = new JFrame();
  jf.setSize(x,y);
  jf.setTitle("Title"); 
  jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

The code above should be a good starting point, it creates a blank window. You can then look further into Java Swing and awt for more info.